# PHP JSON to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

In php, I have an array that holds a list of arrays that has a list of arrays.

```
$data = array();
$driveArr = array();

I have a loop that 

array_push($driveArr, array("text" => $text,
                      "spot" => $play,
                      "ball" => $hasball,
                      "togo" => $togo,
                      "type" => $type,
                      "drive"=> $drive)
Then, array_push($data,$driveArr);
$driveArr=array(); //resets $driveArr then go back to the top of the loop
```

so, $data has bunch of $driveArr

then, i did echo json_encode($data); but it give me blank page.

the overall goal is that i can use this array of array of array in javascript

```
 var data = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>");
```

and i want to see how it's structured so i can pick out middle group of array at a time and access text, spot,ball,togo, type, drive.

i guess my first question is how is json structure so i can at least debug it.

i know it's

```
     $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
     echo json_encode($arr);

     = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

in php, i did

```
$driveNum = 1;
foreach($data as $x=>$x_value){
foreach($x_value as $y=>$y_value){
    foreach($y_value as $z=>$z_value){
    if ($x == $driveNum){
        echo "Key=" . $z . ", Value=" . $z_value;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    }
}
}
```

and everything has saved correctly. I want to access it via  $driveNum = ; in javascript

so let's say everything worked. i dont know if it did or not. and i have var data in javascript.
how do i use data to pick out an array of arrays and individually access text,spot,ball,togo,type and drive?

Comment: add this before the `echo json_encode();`: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: do a print_r($data) to make sure the array actually holds the data you think it's holding

Comment: `JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>");` What do you suppose will happen in the extremely likely event that your JSON has double-quotes?

Comment: wouldn't it work if you just leave the doublequotes?  `var data = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>);`

Comment: I think you dont have to parse the json twice. So `var data = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>");` can simply changed to `var data = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;`. Do you get the expected result when using `var_dump` on $data ?

Comment: yes i did print_r($data); and it has everything fine.

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/json'); didnt fix it

Comment: i changed to single quotes and that didnt help either

Comment: oh i mean. i just want to at least see it in php via echo json_encode($data); i didnt do javascript yet

Comment: @sofl, im not planning on doing it twice. I need to know how json is structured in php so I know how to correctly access it. eventually i will get rid of json encode in php and just have the javascript one.

Comment: I think when `echo json_encode($data);` prints nothing and $data is a valid array, then problem is at an other place.

Comment: Like @sofl said, I think we're going to need to see some other code as there might be another section of the script that's causing the blank output. Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: @Evan i even just did  $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);echo json_encode($arr); and it prints nothing. and thats straight from the example so it cant be wrong. is it not suppose to echo anything?

Comment: Based of the way you are showing you are doing it you should be able to see the json array in the html code if you View Source. Do you see the json array in the html source? If not are you getting any php errors when it is converting the array to a json array?

Comment: it depends, is this part of an AJAX request? if so, it simply returns the data back to the AJAX call, it doesn't "print" anything. Otherwise, it would print this:

{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}